# dynamically add properties or behaviors or function into the $scope of an angular.js controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I like to breakup my code into tiny pieces as possible. So I am looking whether it is possible to separate my controller's $scope properties and functions/behaviors from the controller's braces (scope) and write it far away anywhere else but somewhere inside myApp's scope (may be inside different *.js file and just include it in the HTML file)

my code sample looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

myApp.controller('login', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = data.title;
    $scope.lab = data.lab;

//Following is the set of code that i will use to create the login validation logic. 
//I plan to put these in a new function/behavior in this same $scope.
//BUT i want these lines of code to lie outside this controller function braces.
    if ($scope.email== l.email && $scope.password== l.password) {
        $scope.Loginstatus = false;
    } else {
        $scope.Loginstatus = true;
    }
}]);
```

What I am expecting is something like this:

```
//Now, I know the following is going to be too crude/dirty/illogical but I am trying to explain what is in my mind. 
//Please forgive :) 

    myApp.controller.login.$scope.validate = function($scope){
        if ($scope.email== l.email && $scope.password== l.password) {
            $scope.Loginstatus = false;
        } else {
            $scope.Loginstatus = true;
        }
    };
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: This question is really broad, so I'm voting to close, please read [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/) or something similar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking your app into smaller modules is always profitable for readability and maintenance.

**[See this 13 steps on how to modularize an angular project](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/)**

To get a quick look of how angularjs projects are written, look at angular-seed project:https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Normally, defining methods and variables of a scope should be done in scope itself.

In very rare cases will you need to modify scope properties outside the controller:

In that case you could get the scope outside the controller and use it.

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getelementById('el')).scope()
scope.$apply(function(){
    // do whatever with scope

    scope.validate = function() {
        if (scope.email== l.email && scope.password== l.password) {
            scope.Loginstatus = false;
        } else {
            scope.Loginstatus = true;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for something in this line :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

myApp.controller('login', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = data.title;
    $scope.lab = data.lab;

//Following is the set of code that i will use to create the login validation logic. 
//I plan to put these in a new function/behavior in this same $scope.
//BUT i want these lines of code to lie outside this controller function braces.
    $scope.login = validater({name:$scope.name, password:$scope.password});
}]);

var validater = function(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email== l.email && credentials.password== l.password) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```